# How to get past the last element and get back to the begining of an array in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got this array in JS :

```
const musicNotes = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B'];
```

My user will choose in a HTML select list a note which the value will be stored in a variable `tonalityNote`.

This `tonalityNote` will be passed to a function, for example this one :

```
getThirdDegreeNote(tonalityNote) {
        /* Get the index of tonalityNote in the array musicNotes */
        const tonalityNoteIndex = musicNotes.indexOf(tonalityNote);
        /* Get the value on the index tonalityNoteIndex + 2 in the array musicNotes */
        return musicNotes[tonalityNoteIndex + 4];
    }
```

If tonalityNote = 'C' (first element of the musicNotes array), no problem: It will always work.

But let's say tonalityNote = 'B', then it will not work, because `musicNotes[tonalityNoteIndex + 4]` will return undefined.

Is there anyway to get back to the begining of the array when doing things like this ?

For example, let's say I'm in the index with the value 'B' in the `musicNotes` array, and I want that if I `return musicNotes[tonalityNoteIndex + 4]`, it will return 'D#' (*see the array 'musicNotes' and count + 4 from 'B' to understand what I mean*).

I hope I'm clear enough. I'm really struggling with this one.

Thx by advance.

Comment: modulo operator `%`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, it worked!
I'm quite impressed I have to say, I didn't think this could be the solution.
Again, thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(tonalityNoteIndex + 4) % musicNotes.length` as the index. This will return back the node from begining if the index exceed the length of `musicNotes`  array.

```js
const musicNotes = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B'];
function getThirdDegreeNote(tonalityNote) {
  /* Get the index of tonalityNote in the array musicNotes */
  const tonalityNoteIndex = musicNotes.indexOf(tonalityNote);
  /* Get the value on the index tonalityNoteIndex + 2 in the array musicNotes */
  return musicNotes[(tonalityNoteIndex + 4) % musicNotes.length];
}

console.log(getThirdDegreeNote('C'));
console.log(getThirdDegreeNote('B'));
```

Comment: Probably because it has been asked plenty of times before. Did you search for a duplicate before answering? You have the VTC privilege. Please use it.